# Android sensor callback behavior

Tags: java, android, multithreading, callback

I'm working with a friend trying to develop an android application to track movement by numerically integrating acceleration. We are mechanical engineering students and having trouble understanding how the order of events is occurs within the threads used in an android application. For example it appears that the UI thread runs before the code that called it can finish executing. See the following code that just attempts to get the current acceleration and store the previous acceleration for later use in trapezoidal integration:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {
  float[] current;
  float[] last;
  SensorManager sm;
  Sensor accelerometer;
  TextView Display;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    current = new float[] {0, 0, 0};
    last = new float[] {0, 0, 0};
    sm = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    accelerometer = sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    sm.registerListener(this, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    Display = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_box);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) { 
    last = current;
    current = event.values;

    if (last != current) {
      Display.setText(Arrays.toString(current)+"\n"+Arrays.toString(last)+"\nThe numbers are not the same!!!");
    } else { 
      Display.setText(Arrays.toString(current)+"\n"+Arrays.toString(last)+"\nThe numbers are the same!!!");
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

  }
}
```

The result is that the TextView always displays "the numbers are the same" text.The acceleration values change but the printed current and last values are always the same (ie "[.4423,.12234,9.8234]\n[.4423,.12234,9.8234]\nThe values are the same"). We put a counter in the code to see how often the if statement detects that the values are different and it only increments to one, which I assumes happens on the first iteration. I can't come up with any good theory why the values would change with time but the current and last values are never different. Can the UI thread somehow get the value of last before it is updated by the sensor manager thread? Should I have to deal with handling the order of thread execution if I didn't explicitly create one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so the problem was a fundamental misunderstanding of how Java works. We were passing around the pointers to the array. I have worked with c++ before and thought that since java doesn't use pointers that setting arrays equal to one another was equivalent to passing by value. Doing this actually just set the reference to the current and last variables equal to the reference to the events.value array, which means that the setText function was told to print the values from the same reference. This was a painful way to learn, the Professor who gave us this project is the third person who said to me "if you understand C++, you'll understand java", when he should have said go read a book on the specifics...

To run the above code running we changed:

```
last = current;
current = event.values;
```

to this:

```
System.arraycopy(current,0,last,0,3);
System.arraycopy(event.values, 0, current, 0, 3);
```

Comment: Copying event.values also solves a possible nasty side effect that you could run into in the future. You cannot hold into any value of the event directly (eg. assigning event.values to a global variable) since these values might be reused by the framework (aka using a pointer to the same structure). From tthe Android documentation: "NOTE: The application doesn't own the event object passed as a parameter and therefore cannot hold on to it. The object may be part of an internal pool and may be reused by the framework."